# How does PostGIS store data types?

Tags: postgis, wkt

Does PostGIS store its data types using the [WKT binary encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry#:%7E:text=Well%2Dknown%20binary%5Bedit%5D)? Or does it use its own custom binary format? Where can I find more information on how the storage layer works in the PostGIS library?

If helpful: https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/f6def67654c25d812446239036cee44812613748/postgis/geobuf.c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It stores data in its own internal format, which is neither EWKT nor EWKB. To learn details, you have to read the source.